# How to get the new iOS 8 keyboard show up on my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a iOS phone app which I wrote for iOS 7. I noticed that when I run my app on iOS 8 devices like the IPhone 6 and click on the text field, the keyboard appears stretched. I want to update my code to use the new iOS 8 default keyboard,but not sure how.
I set up my Xcode project to now use size classes, but it still uses the old keyboard. How do i tell Xcode to use the new keyboard?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't clear. What new keyboard? How is the keyboard stretched? Show a screenshot of the problem (and how it should look).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** changed icon to launch image file in below answer. Thanks for pointing @rmaddy.

Add launch screen file for iPhone 6(Retina HD 4.7 & 5.5) by selecting iOS8 and later in attributes inspector of images.xcassets. App will now be installed as app developed/compatible for iphone6 screen size.

Comment: Don't you mean the "launch screen file" instead of "icon file"?

Comment: @rmaddy, you are right. its launch screen file. checked in Xcode now.